# "I would be very happy if I could have..." Is this natural sentence with manners?

Tags: grammar, expressions, formality, email

> I would be very happy if I could have such an opportunity to see you in person, so please let me know whenever (if?) you will have a chance to visit this area.

Is this natural sentence with manners?

Someone who referred me to a new job said she would like to visit my place to make sure the job will start smoothly. I would like to show my appreciation in reply, but I do not force her to come here because it is really far, and would like to keep it as optional.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the reply has been sent/ visit has happened now, but I will answer anyway as it has been bumped by something.

This is a very clunky sentence. Lets start with the first half

> I would be very happy if I could have such an opportunity to see you
>   in person

the "If I could have" is fine at the very start of a clause for example

> "Ladies and Gentlemen, if I could have a moment of your time".

It is not okay in the middle, it stops the flow, I am going to get all poetic a sentence is a river it should flow smoothly downstream. That phrase is a huge bolder stopping the river flowing smoothly, it makes the talker/ reader have to manoeuvre around it.

How would i word this? I would replace that whole boulder with the simple phrase "for the"

**I would be very happy for the opportunity to see you in person**

So onto the second part

> so please let me know whenever (if?) you will have a chance to visit
>   this area.

once again "you will have a chance" doesn't flow but this is ok in the current construct as the brackets are read as commas making it the start of a new clause. 
Take the If out and try to read this clause out loud using a natural pace, "whenever you will have a chance" is quite a tongue twister.

So what would I say

**so please let me know whenever you will be visiting the area**

the word whenever implies it maybe not happening.

> **whenever**
>
> CONJUNCTION
>
> **1** At whatever time; on whatever occasion
>   (emphasizing a lack of restriction)
>
> ‘you can ask for help whenever you need it’

Hopefully somebody will be along to correct/ explain the grammar of it all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "I would be happy If you would" is less emphatic and accommodative.Ther is no imposition, just a simple wish. The wish could be granted or not. The process is still unfolding. Whereas,, on the other hand," if you could", shows  a complete course of action that has already occured in the past. It could point to utter hopelessness and disappointment that a certain course of action did not unfold as expected. .

Answer (score -1):

I'd reply with something like this:

"Thanks for the offer. I wouldn't want to impose, but I would really appreciate it if you could."

Comment: "I wouldn't want to impose" sounds more like the person writing is planning a visit, not insisting that another person visit them. I don't think answers the question very well.

Comment: @J.R., not sure why you believe the only kind of imposition would be if the person is planning a visit. I'd imagine it would be an imposition if I were to inconvenience another person in any way and certainly I'd consider this other person going out of their way to come here and make the OP settle in an inconvenience on them, and mention it if only to show them that I understand that it is out of their way and that I appreciate it.

Comment: I didn't say it couldn't – and I certainly don't think that's the "only kind of imposition." But I read the question a few times, and your answer a few times, and it just didn't seem like a very good match.